# Expected type '_SpecialForm[str]', got 'str' instead

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

I'm trying to create a BQ table schema, as seen on this [page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables)

But I get a compilation error for all the `mode="REQUIRED"`

I didn't see anything special to import but the bq module.

```
Expected type '_SpecialForm[str]', got 'str' instead
```

The code:

```
    bqServiceWrapper.create_table(_ADS_TO_REMOVE_TABLE_NAME,
                                  [
                                      bigquery.SchemaField("add_id", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
                                      bigquery.SchemaField("timestamp_str", "TIMESTAMP", mode="REQUIRED"),
                                      bigquery.SchemaField("timestamp", "TIMESTAMP", mode="REQUIRED")
                                  ])
```

BTW does the python BQ library allows [creating a table without a schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_an_empty_table_without_a_schema_definition) (like Java does?). If so - how can the type to implied as `"TIMESTAMP"` and not `"STRING"`?

Comment: I have updated the answer for the second part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be an extra `mode=”REQUIRED”` in your code. Also, your code is not creating a table as mentioned in the doc `table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)` . Rewriting your code as follows :

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()


client.create_table(bigquery.Table("ProjectID.Dataset.Table", schema= [
                                   bigquery.SchemaField("add_id", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
                                   bigquery.SchemaField("timestamp_str", "TIMESTAMP", mode="REQUIRED"),
                                    bigquery.SchemaField("timestamp", "TIMESTAMP", mode="REQUIRED")
                                ]))
```

This creates the table in BigQuery with the required schema :[image]

For creating a schemaless table using the Python client library you can simply run the above code without the schema : `client.create_table(bigquery.Table("ProjectID.Dataset.Table"))` or directly `client.create_table("ProjectID.Dataset.Table")`.
But if we are creating a schemaless table we need to define the schema either by auto-detect or manually and only then we can add data to it. Assuming you are trying to load data from a CSV file into an empty table with auto-detect schema, you need to have the Timestamp data in the supported format as specified in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#limitations).

Comment: The extra `required` was a copy paste issue. Regarding the signature, it has actually worked for me.

Comment: Hi @EladBenda, Could you please clarify what is the issue you are facing? Because the code I provided, is creating the BigQuery table with the schema that you mentioned.

Comment: how do I enable "auto-detect"?

Comment: Please refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#python) for enabling schema auto-detection. The documentation shows how to enable "auto-detect" using the Client Libraries.